# If range contains any "-1" then. If range contains any "0" then. If each cell in range contains "1" then. Else

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to color a commandbutton in a userform based on values within a range of cells in a worksheet. If any cell contains a -1 the button is red. If any cell contains 0 the button is yellow. If all cells contain 1 the button is green. Else, the button is white.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

UserForm29.Hide
UserForm1.Label1 = TextBox1.Value

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

'10
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3:C11")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "-1" Then
        UserForm1.CommandButton1.BackColor = vbRed
    ElseIf cell.Value = "0" Then
        UserForm1.CommandButton1.BackColor = vbYellow
    ElseIf cell.Value = "1" Then
        UserForm1.CommandButton1.BackColor = vbGreen
    Else
        UserForm1.CommandButton1.BackColor = vbWhite
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: What happens if one cell contains -1 and one contains 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really loop because you'll just keep resetting conditions and as I understand it the conditions are prioritized.  That is, any -1 will override any 0.  Also, the only value that really matters is the last one in the loop, if set up this way.  I would suggest that you use Range.Find for the first two.  If you can find the value, then it's matched, and then you should exit the function.  For the third, extract the unique values from the range, and you have matched the condition if the array has one element of value 1.  Otherwise return your default result (white).  This is not a sub, but a function that demonstrates the idea:

```
Function getColor(rng As Range) As Variant
    
    Dim buffer As Variant
    
    Set buffer = rng.Find("-1")
    If Not buffer Is Nothing Then getColor = vbRed: Exit Function
    
    Set buffer = rng.Find("0")
    If Not buffer Is Nothing Then getColor = vbYellow: Exit Function
    
    buffer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Unique(rng))
    If UBound(buffer) = 1 And buffer(1) = 1 Then getColor = vbGreen: Exit Function
    
    getColor = vbWhite
    
End Function
```

To test just pass the range that has the values in it to the function.  You can make changes in the range to demonstrate the different outcomes.  You can then implement the core idea however you need to.

---

TRANSPOSE is used here because of the way that unique returns values depending on the input.  Ubound(buffer) is always going to return a number, regardless of the number of elements in the array, but if there are more than one buffer(1) is going to throw an error.

If you don't want to use worksheet functions (or your version of Excel doesn't have these available), it's fairly simple to write a different check.  This would be an appropriate place to use the loop, something like this:

```
Dim matched As Boolean: matched = True
For Each c In rng
    If c.Value <> 1 Then matched = False
    Next
If matched Then getColor = vbGreen: Exit Function
```

Comment: Where would I put that function? The Program is set up where I press a button that opens UserForm1 with 27 CommandButtons. Those CommandButtons take you to UserForms that have subsections. I have a Sheet1 with table that has a value of -1, 0, 1, "". Fail, incomplete, pass, not started. The 27 CommandButtons on UserForm1 need to be colored and their values are from Sheet1.

Comment: I'm just saying put that function in the vba editor so you can use it.  Set up some data so that you can test the function (or test it against the data you already have).  If it does what you want, then you just take the conditions out of it and put them in your current code where ever the ones you're using now are.  A sample of the sheet you are targeting would be helpful, otherwise I'm just trying to guess how you have it set up.

Comment: The color logic is separate from how you are using it in your presentation, and you never show how it is going to be used, so I just addressed the logic determination issue.